# Regex each line of stdout and push to array in shell/bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, amazon-s3

I am using AWS CLI to `ls` an S3 bucket. The output is:

```
Austins-MacBook-Pro:~ austin$ aws s3 ls s3://obscured-bucket-name
                       PRE 2016-02-24-03-42/
                       PRE 2016-02-25-22-25/
                       PRE 2016-02-26-00-34/
                       PRE 2016-02-26-00-42/
                       PRE 2016-02-26-03-43/
```

Using either Bash or Shell script I need to take each line and remove the spaces or tabs and the `PRE` before the prefix names and put each prefix in an array so I can use it to subsequently `rm` the oldest folder.

## TLDR;

I need to turn the output of `aws s3 ls s3://obscured-bucket-name` to an array of values like this: `2016-02-26-03-43/`

Thanks for reading!

Comment: pipe the output to `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://obscured-bucket-name | sed -e "s/[^0-9]*//"
```

so if you want to get the oldest folder:

```
aws s3 ls s3://obscured-bucket-name | sed -e "s/[^0-9]*//" | sort | head -n 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 4):

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could:

```
mapfile myarray < <(aws s3 ls s3://obscured-bucket-name)
echo ${myarray[@]#*PRE }
2016-02-24-03-42/ 2016-02-25-22-25/ 2016-02-26-00-34/ 2016-02-26-00-42/ 2016-02-26-03-43/
```

or

```
mapfile -t myarray < <(aws s3 ls s3://obscured-bucket-name)
myarray=( "${myarray[@]#*PRE }" )
printf '<%s>\n' "${myarray[@]%/}"
<2016-02-24-03-42>
<2016-02-25-22-25>
<2016-02-26-00-34>
<2016-02-26-00-42> 
<2016-02-26-03-43>
```

Nota:  `-t` switch remove a trailing newline from each line read.

See `help mapfile` and/or `man -Pless\ +/readarray bash`

`mapfile` was introduced in 2009 with version **4** of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

Comment: I think I prefer the use of ```sed``` it's more readable and seems to be more widely supported than ```mapfile```, but thank you for the comment!

Comment: This is a lot quicker than using a fork to `sed`. `mapfile` is a [tag:bash] builtin. See `help readarray`,  `help mapfile` and `help read`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in ```bash 3.2``` under ```OSX 10.10.5```.

Comment: @F.Hauri, nice solution +1

Comment: @user2687646 `mapfile` was introduced in 2009, with version 4 of bash!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use awk to the rescue

```
aws s3 ls <s3://obscured-bucket-name>/ | awk '/PRE/ { print $2 }' | tail -n+2
```

This will remove the last bucket and provide store the folders in the array variable.